# Making the SE handle for the jQuery UI resizable plugin lock in the aspect ratio

Tags: jquery

The jQuery `resize` plugin has a SE grip area for dragging east and south simultaneously, but it allows you to also just drag east or south,  so if you're not careful you can easily drag east or south accidentally and destroy the aspect ratio of your object. I'd like to make the SE handle always lock in `aspectRatio:true`  so this can't happen.

In the `jsfiddle` at http://jsfiddle.net/f9Vwp/2/ I sense a mouse hover over the SE corner and  then reconfigure the resizable option with `aspectRatio : true`, before any resizing starts:

```
var resizeOps1 = {
    handles : 'n,s,se,w,e'
}
var resizeOps2 = {
    handles : 'n,s,se,w,e',
    aspectRatio:true
}
```

But it doesn't work.  Does anyone see what the problem might be?

Thanks

Comment: If you hold shift, it'll maintain aspect ratio for you.

Comment: Yes, but that's not as intuitive as just dragging from the corner.

Comment: After digging around i don't see a way of doing this with the available options and events. The start event happens to late, mouse events on the handler trigger all over the place, etc.

Comment: How about having the SE hover handler "destroy" the resizablility for that element and then recreate it with the aspectRatio : true flag?

Another way might be to have the SE  hover handler do "whatever gets done" when the user holds down the shift key, since that also forces resizable to maintain the aspect ratio, even when resizable was created without the aspectRatio : true flag.

I'll keep playing with this, but do you see any light with these approaches?

Comment: the problem is the hover keeps getting triggered back and forth as it gets resized.

Comment: Ah!  Ok.  Thanks for digging that out. Getting more desparate, how about this: we create a flag in $ space, like "resizable_hold_aspect_ratio" and we modify the ui-resizable code to do the same thing when it sees the flag as when it sees the shift key down: if(shift_key || resizable_hold_aspect_ratio){...}. We set the flag on a mousedown in a 10x10 square in the se corner, and let the event bubble up to the resizable code so it still sees the start of the resize. The resize stop handler clears the flag.